# MVVM galasoft messaging

Tags: wpf

```
      Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<User>>(this,
            LoginToken.SuccessUser, ViewMainWindow);

      var successMsg = new NotificationMessage<User>(user,
                string.Empty);
            Messenger.Default.Send(successMsg, LoginToken.SuccessUser);
```

I tried using galasoft version and want to try eventaggregator. is this right way or i have to use eventaggregator?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find messaging to be an anti pattern, but here you go anyways.

[Check out this similiar question here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22848454/2285592)

Cheers

Stian

Comment: So how would you do it instead of messaging?

Comment: I use services and TDD, so i feed my viewmodels a bunch of interfaces basicly. These servies may be shared. Another way is to use a viewmodellocator, but beware not to couple your viewmodels to much(you may want to use them in other projects/scenarios)! The thing about messaging any why I find it an antipattern is that you have "no control of a viewmodels dependencies", you have loose coupling ofc and it has benefits. I used to use it some 4 years ago or something.